# Add a button on my winform to run the Snipping Tool application

Tags: c#, winforms, button, hyperlink

I am trying to run SnippingTool application application by clicking a button on my Winform project. I've tried use these three functions below individually:

```
   private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Process SnippingTool = new Process();
            String FilePath = @"C:\WINDOWS\system32\SnippingTool.exe";
            SnippingTool.StartInfo.FileName = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(FilePath);
            SnippingTool.StartInfo.Arguments = "SnippingTool.exe";
            SnippingTool.Start();
        }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\SnippingTool.exe");
}

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\WINDOWS\system32\SnippingTool.exe");
}
```

However nothing works. I always get two error messages.

Or by using the first function it would open the C:\WINDOWS\system32 folder and not start the application.

Could you please help?

Comment: First Error:An unhandled exception of type 'System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception' occurred in System.dll

Comment: Come on! Name __all__ the erroros __and__ the lines that bring them up!! do you think we are here to guess?? - Ther 2nd buttons3 is a) duplicate and b) has wrong slashes.. Also the exe is not an argument, leave that out! And if the path is right, why not simply set it???

Comment: Second One: is operation error

Comment: You also probably do not have enough rights to start anything from that directory.

Comment: Hello TaW, Sorry for the late reply. I am not using all three functions at once. At each time I debug the Project using only one of the functions.

Comment: First one is:
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception' occurred in System.dl

Second One:
"Unhandled exception has occurred in your application....etc" 

Or if I use the first function above it would open the folder System32 and not the application SnippingTool.exe

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are probably just calling the wrong exe for your enviroment.
Try

```
        Process snippingToolProcess = new Process();
        snippingToolProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        if (!Environment.Is64BitProcess)
        {
            snippingToolProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\Windows\\sysnative\\SnippingTool.exe";
            snippingToolProcess.Start(); 
        }
        else
        {
            snippingToolProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\Windows\\system32\\SnippingTool.exe";
            snippingToolProcess.Start();            
        }
```

Comment: @user2698932 I don't know who you are...But sir you are awesome! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```js
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Process proc = new Process();
            proc.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\WINDOWS\system32\SnippingTool.exe";
            proc.Start();
        }
```

it works for me...

well, try this:

```js
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Process proc = new Process();
            proc.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\WINDOWS\system32\SnippingTool.exe";
            proc.StartInfo.UserName = "Your Username";
            proc.StartInfo.Password = "Your Password";
            proc.Start();
        }
```

add Username and Password to your proccess info

Comment: I'm afraid it's not working. I'm getting an error:
"Unhandled exception has occurred in your application....etc"

Any suggestions?

Comment: can you post or send to me the entire error text (Exception)

Comment: Does this really work for you? Starting a program from __that__ directory?? I get a _file not found_ error, which is certainly because the process lacks the priviledges for that folder.. I can copy it elsewhere and start it from there, though.

Comment: what windows are you using?

Comment: I could copy it elsewhere but it brought up one of those cute error messageboxes with emoty title and empty text... Calling it via the virtual Sysnative  folder did the job for me (W8.1 64bit). So I was wrong about the priviledges.

Comment: Yeah, using it through user2698932 code above did the job for me too...However, thank you for your effort I really appreciate it!